# group collection data by multiple fields mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

Collection Structure

```
Order = new Schema
    index:          { type: Number, unique: true }
    number:         Date
    status:         { type: String, enum: ['success', 'failure'] }
    created_at:     { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    updated_at:     { type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

I need help with a query that returns me an array of objects having data as success count and failure count grouped by date.
Ex-

```
orders = {
              28-10-2016:{
               success_count: 10, 
               failure_count: 10
              },
              29-10-2016: {
               success_count: 10, 
               failure_count: 10
              }
          }
```

Comment: Please Post here what you have tried so far

Comment: @chridam I wanted him to post the code in question and not in the comments, may it is not conveyed to him properly in my comment :-)

Answer (score 6):

With the aggregation framework, the result will be slightly different from your "desired" output as instead of having hash keys, you get an array of objects with the `_id` key having a value that represents you group by field. For instance, instead of

```
{
    "28-10-2016":{
        "success_count": 10, 
        "failure_count": 10
    },
    "29-10-2016": {
        "success_count": 10, 
        "failure_count": 10
    }
}
```

you'd have a better structure like

```
[
    {
        "_id": "28-10-2016",
        "success_count": 10, 
        "failure_count": 10
    },
        "_id": "29-10-2016",
        "success_count": 10, 
        "failure_count": 10
    }
]
```

Accomplishing the above result would require using the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator in the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator operator. The **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator will evaluate a logical condition based on its first argument (if) and then returns the second argument where the evaluation is true (then) or the third argument where false (else). This converts the true/false logic into 1 and 0 numerical values that feed into **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** respectively:

```
"success_count": {
    "$sum": {
        "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "success" ] }, 1, 0 ]
    }
}
```

As a resulting pipeline, one needs to run the aggregation operation which uses the **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)** operator in the `_id` key expression for the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline:

```
Orders.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$dateToString": { 
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                    "date": "$created_at" 
                }
            },
            "success_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "success" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "failure_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "failure" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
], function (err, orders){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(orders);
})
```

---

However, there is a more flexible and better performant approach which executes much faster than the above, where the most efficient data structure for your aggregation result follows the schema for example:

```
orders = [
    {
        "_id": "28-10-2016",
        "counts": [
            { "status": "success", "count": 10 },
            { "status": "failure", "count": 10 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "29-10-2016",
        "counts": [
            { "status": "success", "count": 10 },
            { "status": "failure", "count": 10 }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then consider running an alternative pipeline as follows

```
Orders.aggregate([
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "date":  {
                    "$dateToString": { 
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                        "date": "$created_at" 
                    }
                },
                "status": { "$toLower": "$status" }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.date",
            "counts": {
                "$push": {
                    "status": "$_id.status",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    }
], function (err, orders){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(orders);
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you @chridam!